# Scope of pointer to structures in c?

Tags: c, pointers, graph, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct GNode{
    struct gnode* nextnode;
    struct gnode* arcptr;
    int Visited;
}

typedef struct GNode* Grnd;

struct ArcNode{
    struct arcnode* nextarc;
    struct acrnode* ndptr;
}

typedef struct ArcNode* Arc;

Grnd getGraphNode(){
    Grnd NewNode=(Grnd)malloc(sizeof(struct GNode));

    NewNode->nextnode=NULL;
    NewNode->arcptr=NULL;

    return NewNode;
}

Arc getArcNode(){
    Arc NewArc=(Arc)malloc(sizeof(struct ArcNode));

    NewArc->nextarc=NULL;
    NewArc->ndptr=NULL;

    return NewArc;
}

void join(Grnd *GNode1,Grnd *GNode2){
    Arc NewArc=getArcNode();
    NewArc->ndptr=(*GNode2);

    NewArc->nextarc=(*GNode1)->arcptr;
    (*GNode1)->arcptr=NewArc;
}  

Grnd addNode(Grnd *Graph){
    Grnd NewNode=getGraphNode();

    if((*Graph)==NULL){
        (*Graph)=NewNode;  
        return NewNode;
    }

    while((*Graph)->nextnode!=NULL)
        Graph=Graph->nextnode;

    (*Graph)->nextnode=NewNode;

    return NewNode;  
}
```

Considering the above C code : I am worried that when I call the `join` function to join two graph nodes, will it actually join them? because as soon as the program goes out of the scope of `join` , `NewArc` doesn't exist. So when I try to find all the adjacent Nodes to a given node after creating the graph,will I be able to? and Why?

Comment: But `NewArc` is just a pointer type, yes?  The pointed-to memory was allocated by `malloc()`, and will continue to be valid until freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because as soon as the program goes out of the scope of join , NewArc
>   doesn't exist.

That's right! The pointer itself disappears, **but the memory it points to is still there**, allocated for you. So you are free to continue to refer to it via other pointers, until you `free` it.

---

```
(*GNode1)->arcptr=NewNode;
```

I think you meant `NewArc` instead of `NewNode` ?

Comment: No. NewNode is not even a variable in join.I created NewArc,which is a new Arc node , representing the arc emanating from GNode1 and terminating in GNode2. and I am putting that arc node in front of  the adjacency list of arcs emanating from GNode1.